# Insert and delete end points are not storing or removing data in a Postgres database but showing a success status response in postman

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, postman

The insert and delete end points are not storing or removing data in a Postgres database but showing a success response in postman. GET requests are all working fine though. Using queries to create and deleting records on pgAdmin query tool or DBeaver is giving me the desired result.

The controller on the below screeen shows the implementation of my POST and DELETE requests.

```
const dbConfig = require('../configs/dbconfig')


  const createIncident = async(req,res)=>{
    try {
      let { mine_id, latitude, longitude, description, severity } = req.body;
      console.log("Received data", mine_id, latitude, longitude, description, severity)

      const query = 'INSERT INTO incidents (mine_id,latitude,longitude,description,severity) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *';
      const values = [mine_id, latitude, longitude, description, severity];

      const result = await dbConfig.pool.query(query,values);
      await dbConfig.pool.query('COMMIT')

      res.status(201).send({message:'Incident inserted successfully',result});
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error inserting data',error);
      res.status(500).json({error:'Internal server error'});
      
    }
  };


const deleteIncident = (request, response) => {
  const id = parseInt(request.params.id)

  dbConfig.pool.query('DELETE FROM incidents WHERE id = $1', [id], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    response.status(200).send(`User deleted with ID: ${id}`)
  })
}
  module.exports = {
    createIncident,
    deleteIncident 
  }
```

The router is as below:

```
module.exports = app => {
    const incidents = require("../controllers/incidents.controller.js");
  
    var router = require("express").Router();

  
    router.post("/incidents", incidents.createIncident);
    router.delete("/incidents/:id",incidents.deleteIncident);
    
    
    app.use("/api", router);
  };
```

The app.js file is as below:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 5000;

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200'
}));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false,
  })
);


require("./routes/incidents.routes")(app);


app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log(`running on ${port}`)
});
```

Dependencies installed are;

```
{
  "name": "mine_incidents",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "People centred mining modernization",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
 
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "pg": "^8.11.3",
    "pg-promise": "^11.5.4",
    "postgres": "^3.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

The params passed in postman are as follows and the result. These response shows a 201 status but no actual data is created on the DB or deleted. I do notice that the prebuildEmptyResultObject references nulls. I don't know if this has any bearing in posting the JSON.

[image: POSTMAN data,response and results]

Any help will be appreciated.

I looked at the pgAdmin restriction properties to check if a write/delete to the DB is permitted. All the permissions have been checked.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code as text, not as images. [This is why that's important](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Thank you!

Comment: Also, did you make sure you are sending the correct `Content-Type: application/json` in your request?

Comment: @CherryDT, I have added the code used. Yes the content-type is application/json

Comment: The issue was on my end where I was looking at the wrong DB instance. The tables have been updated.